# PHP - Inheritance through foreach loop

Tags: php

I'm facing a behavior that I don't understand and which causes big issues in my project.

In a `foreach` loop through an iterable object, during the definition of an associative array, a certain `key => value` pair must be set only if a certain `if` condition is fullfilled. When it isn't, it shouldn't do anything.

However, what's happening is that when the condition isn't fullfilled, while it shouldn't do anything, it still runs the code inside the `if` brackets and the data correspond to the wrong item of the iterable object we are running through. Outside of the condition, everything seems to work well.

Concretely :

```
foreach ($study->children() as $rawPart) {
   $isAnnex = $rawPart->template()->name() === 'annex';
   
   $preparedPart;
   $preparedPart['title'] = (string)$rawPart->title();
   $preparedPart['type'] = (string)$rawPart->template()->name();
   // …etc.

   if ($isAnnex) {
      $preparedPart['title2'] = (string)$rawPart->title();
   }
}
```

When `$isAnnex` is `false`, the above code sets the value of $preparedPart['title2'] with the title of the last `$rawPart` traversed during the loop which was an annex.

Here is the result in Json :

```
{
  "parts": [
    {
      "title": "Edito de Christo…",
      "type": "annex",
      "title2": "Edito de Christo…"
    },
    { 
      "title": "Introduction", 
      "type": "annex", 
      "title2": "Introduction" 
    },
    {
      "title": "M\u00e9thodologie",
      "type": "annex",
      "title2": "M\u00e9thodologie"
    },
    {
      "title": "Le projet et l'organisation",
      "type": "part",
      "title2": "M\u00e9thodologie"
    },
    {
      "title": "L\u2019adresse aux publics",
      "type": "part",
      "title2": "M\u00e9thodologie"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I remove the condition, `$preparedPart['title']` and `$preparedPart['title2']` are identical :

```
foreach ($study->children() as $rawPart) {
   $isAnnex = $rawPart->template()->name() === 'annex';
   
   $preparedPart;
   $preparedPart['title'] = (string)$rawPart->title();
   $preparedPart['type'] = (string)$rawPart->template()->name();
   // …etc.

   $preparedPart['title2'] = (string)$rawPart->title();
}
```

Result in Json :

```
{
  "parts": [
    {
      "title": "Edito de Christopher Miles, directeur g\u00e9n\u00e9ral de la cr\u00e9ation artistique, Minist\u00e8re de la Culture",
      "type": "annex",
      "title2": "Edito de Christopher Miles, directeur g\u00e9n\u00e9ral de la cr\u00e9ation artistique, Minist\u00e8re de la Culture"
    },
    { "title": "Introduction", "type": "annex", "title2": "Introduction" },
    {
      "title": "M\u00e9thodologie",
      "type": "annex",
      "title2": "M\u00e9thodologie"
    },
    {
      "title": "Le projet et l'organisation",
      "type": "part",
      "title2": "Le projet et l'organisation"
    },
    {
      "title": "L\u2019adresse aux publics",
      "type": "part",
      "title2": "L\u2019adresse aux publics"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm totally lost. Any idea ?

Comment: what are you printing? there is no object with `part` attribute here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
$preparedPart;
```

This statement does nothing. It doesn't declare or assign anything, it just *reads* a variable, and does nothing with it.

So more precisely, your problem is what that line *should* be doing:

```
$preparedPart = [];
```

This *writes to* the variable, clearing any previous data. Without that, *the variable keeps its value each time around the loop*.

A simplified example:

```
foreach ( [1,2,3,4] as $number ) {
   $a = null; // right - will be cleared on every loop 
   $b; // wrong - does nothing, and $b will keep its value until the if statement is true again

   if ( $number % 2 === 1 ) {
      $a = $number;
      $b = $number;
   }

   var_dump($a, $b);
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/s4XZ7